# How to Authenticate Users with API Keys

Tags: rest, symfony

I'm trying to generate API key for our application, but I do not know where to start 
I found a tutorial on the link below 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html#createtoken
but I did not understand how it works, and if I call the function createToken() what are the parameters that I can last 
thank you in advance
any help please

Answer (score 1):

You are starting in the right place.

Think of the ApiKeyAuthenticator as a listener that is fired depending on login request or authentication protocol.

Do not worry about what to pass into this function as its parent class runs the configuration and what to capture pass etc. Basically though it will get from the header request the apikey and authenticate it againt the users account or global

Next you need to configure you firewall and services please next visit this page in the cookbook which will explain it a little better.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html#cookbook-security-api-key-config